# data in real phone not received / But in emulator received ->use AsyncTask and URL

Tags: android, url, android-asynctask, bufferedreader

I have 2 problems. first the Toast get data from my PHP server in emulator but not in real phone with android 5. the app hasn't any crash but just Toast empty .
second problem: when I run app in emulator and click the Button data get empty and for second click data received from server.

this is my simple php code:

```
<?php
    echo "hi";
?>
```

this is Asynctask Class:

```
package com.example.hamed.supermarketone;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class AsyncTaskConnect extends AsyncTask {
    public String link;
    public AsyncTaskConnect(String link){
        this.link= link;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            URL mUrl = new URL(link);
            URLConnection mConnecttion = mUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader mBuffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mConnecttion.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = mBuffReader.readLine())  !=null){
                mStringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            LoginPage.data=mStringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

and my Activity:

```
package com.example.hamed.supermarketone;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String data="";
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout_gotoLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

        mLinearLayout_gotoLogin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnr_gotologin);
        mLinearLayout_gotoLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 new AsyncTaskConnect("http://nikayand.com/app/").execute();
                if (!data.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(G.context, data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Worth a look: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show your toast right after you execute your async task, so there will never be any data there, you have to show the toast in your `onPostExecute` method of your async task.

Also you should not be sending data to a static variable in your activity like this

```
public static String data="";

LoginPage.data=mStringBuilder.toString();
```

that's a bad way to access data

Comment: could you explain more? I'm beginner !

Comment: if possible write your own code

Comment: Technically, there *might* be data there, but no guarantee

Comment: yeah... it's work when I user override methods:
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }